# Android: Alignment/ Layout issues on using different Data Structures

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a custom listview in my application. The needs of the user varies with the option he selects and the result is on the listview. I am representing the same list once by using `ArrayList<String>` and other time, while using  `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`. Now, while using the former i.e. `ArrayList<String>`, the result in the listView row gets aligned perfectly but then, while using the later i.e. `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` the alignment gets worse. I am not understanding what the problem can be. Please help!

Below I am posting the images, code and source code of the XML which is used as a row in my custom Listview.

Images Link: (As I am new user I cannot upload images)

```
Using ArrayList<String>
```

http://i46.tinypic.com/2r2b0g5.jpg

> `Using ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`

http://i47.tinypic.com/11w7tqe.jpg

**Code:**

For ***Arraylist< HashMap< String, String>>***

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> searchList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                  for(int i=0;i<productName.size();i++)
                        {

                         String currentListItem=productName.get(i).toString();

                         if(textLength<=currentListItem.length()){

                          //compare the String in EditText with Names in the ArrayList

                          if(searchText.equalsIgnoreCase(currentListItem.substring(0,textLength))){
                              HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
                              temp.put("PRODUCTNAME",productName.get(i));
                              temp.put("PRODUCTID", productID.get(i));
                              temp.put("BRANDNAME", brandName.get(i));
                              temp.put("VENDORNAME", vendor.get(i));
                              temp.put("OPENINGSTOCK", openingStock.get(i));
                              temp.put("AVAILABLESTOCK", availableStock.get(i));
                              temp.put("ADDSTOCK", addStock.get(i));
                              temp.put("PURCHASRPRICE", purchasePrice.get(i));
                              temp.put("SALESPRICE", salesPrice.get(i));
                              searchList.add(temp);
                             }
                        }
                      }
                        SimpleAdapter aaadapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                new_stock_io.this,
                                searchList,
                                R.layout.list_otcmain123,
                                new String[] {"PRODUCTID", "PRODUCTNAME", "BRANDNAME","VENDORNAME","OPENINGSTOCK","AVAILABLESTOCK","ADDSTOCK","SALESPRICE", "PURCHASEPRICE"},
                                new int[] {R.id.txt_id,R.id.txt_name, R.id.txt_bname, R.id.txt_vendor, R.id.txt_openingstock,R.id.txt_availablestock,R.id.txt_addstock,R.id.txt_salesprice,R.id.txt_purchaseprice}
                                );

                        lv.setAdapter(aaadapter);
```

For **ArrayList< String>**

```
List<String> vendorName = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    List<String> vendorID = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<Object> objectArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
     List<String> stockID = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> picture = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> productID = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> productName = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> brandName = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> vendor = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> openingStock = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> availableStock = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String>  addStock= new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String>  purchasePrice= new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String>  salesPrice= new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> subCategoryID = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> subCategoryName= new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> productCategory= new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> subCategoriesNameArray = new ArrayList<String>();
     List<String> subCategoriesIDArray= new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < productID.size(); i++)
                {
                    Object obj = new Object();
                    objectArray.add(obj);   
                }

 adapter = new ListItemsAdapter(objectArray, 1);

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //List Adapter for listView.
    public class ListItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {
        ViewHolder holder1;

        public ListItemsAdapter(List<Object> items, int x) {
            super(new_stock_io.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_otcmain123, null);

            holder1 = new ViewHolder();

            holder1.tv_id=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            holder1.tv_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);

            holder1.tv_brandname=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_bname);
            holder1.tv_openingstock=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_openingstock);
            holder1.tv_availablestock=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_availablestock);
            holder1.tv_addstock=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_addstock);
            holder1.tv_addstock.setTag(position);

            holder1.tv_addstock.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
            {   
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Object o = (Object)holder1.tv_addstock.getTag();

                    Log.d("method focus", "call");
                    Log.d("position", position+"");
                    Log.d("edit text value", o.toString());
                    Log.d("value",":"+holder1.tv_addstock.getText().toString());
                    addStock.set(position, holder1.tv_addstock.getText().toString());
                }
            });
            holder1.tv_prizeperunit=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_salesprice);
            holder1.tv_vendor=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vendor);
            holder1.tv_prizeperunitpurchase=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_purchaseprice);


            convertView.setTag(holder1);
            if (checkboxClicked==0)
            {
                holder1.tv_addstock.setTag(objectArray.get(position));
                holder1.tv_id.setText(productID.get(position));
                holder1.tv_name.setText(productName.get(position));
                holder1.tv_brandname.setText(brandName.get(position));
                holder1.tv_openingstock.setText(openingStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_availablestock.setText(availableStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_addstock.setId(position);
                holder1.tv_addstock.setText(addStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_prizeperunit.setText(salesPrice.get(position));
                holder1.tv_vendor.setText(vendor_Name);
                holder1.tv_prizeperunitpurchase.setText(purchasePrice.get(position));
            }
            else if (checkboxClicked==1)
            {
                //holder1.tv_addstock.setTag(objectArray.get(position));
                holder1.tv_id.setText(onCheckProductID.get(position));
                holder1.tv_name.setText(onCheckProductName.get(position));
                holder1.tv_brandname.setText(onCheckBrandName.get(position));
                holder1.tv_openingstock.setText(onCheckOpeningStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_availablestock.setText(onCheckAvailableStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_addstock.setId(position);
                holder1.tv_addstock.setText(onCheckAddStock.get(position));
                holder1.tv_prizeperunit.setText(onCheckSalesPrice.get(position));
                holder1.tv_vendor.setText(onCheckVendor.get(position));
                holder1.tv_prizeperunitpurchase.setText(onCheckPurchasePrice.get(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }

    //Simple holder class for above Adapter class.
    public class ViewHolder 
    {
        TextView tv_id,tv_name,tv_brandname,tv_vendor,tv_openingstock,tv_availablestock,tv_addstock,tv_prizeperunit,tv_prizeperunitpurchase;    
    }
```

**XML:**

> ```
>  <LinearLayout
>      android:id="@+id/ll_list_header"
>      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>                 <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_id"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.05"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="ID"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view1"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_name"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.07"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Name"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view2"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view3"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" /> -->
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_bname"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.12"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Brand Name"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view3"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_vendor"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.08"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Vendor"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view27"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_openingstock"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.09"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Opening Stock"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view26"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_availablestock"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.09"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:text="Available Stock"
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"/>
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view25"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_addstock"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="20dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.10"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:hint="Rs."
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" />
>
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view24"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_salesprice"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="20dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.10"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:hint="Rs."
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold" android:width="7dp" />
>             <View
>                 android:id="@+id/view24"
>                 android:layout_width="1dip"
>                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                 android:background="#e5e5e5" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txt_purchaseprice"
>                 android:layout_width="0dp"
>                 android:layout_height="20dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="0.12"
>                 android:gravity="center"
>                 android:hint="Rs."
>                 android:textSize="6dip"
>                 android:textStyle="bold"  android:width="7dp"/>
>    </LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: plz post some images to show the alignment issues. also post code that fills your layout with data

Comment: Sure, Sunil. Wait for a while.

Comment: @sunil: I have edited the Question and have put the links in the same. Check it out.

Comment: also post code that fills your layout with data

Comment: Both data Structure uses different approach/code to fill the list, the Hashmap one fills the list via SimpleAdapter while the simple String one fills it with a custom ListAdapter.

Comment: thats what i thought. if you filled the list with same adapter, it doesn't matter whether you used ArrayList of String or HashMap. So the problem lies in your code itself. not in xml layout. so, post codes of these two portions separately

Comment: @sunil: Check it out now. Have edited the question itself.